# Stop canvas clearing on lineWidth change

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas

I have a react app that allows you to draw and select different line widths.

Code:

```
const [sliderVal, setSliderVal] = useState(1) 
const canvasRef = useRef(null)
useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;


    /* Mouse Capturing Work */
    var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};
    var last_mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
        last_mouse.x = mouse.x;
        last_mouse.y = mouse.y;

        mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

        canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
    }, false);


    /* Drawing on Paint App */
    ctx.lineWidth = sliderVal;
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
    }, false);

    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint, false);
    }, false);

    var onPaint = function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(last_mouse.x, last_mouse.y);
        ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    };
}, [sliderVal])
```

I'm trying to make it so if sliderVal changes the whole canvas wont re-render only the line width will. Right now it works but if I select a new lineWidth the whole canvas gets cleared.

Comment: Could you add the part where you draw on your canvas? or a codesandbox

Comment: Just edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you not to use the eventListener in that way, canvas in `ReactJS` already has some methods to which you can access and pass a function. This new way of handling the `canvas` solves your problem:

```
  const [sliderVal, setSliderVal] = useState(1);
  const [mouse, setMouse] = useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    lastX: 0,
    lastY: 0,
    click: false
  });
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  const paint = (e) => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    setMouse({
      ...mouse,
      x: e.pageX - bounds.left - window.scrollX,
      y: e.pageY - bounds.top - window.scrollY,
      lastX: mouse.x,
      lastY: mouse.y
    });
    ctx.lineWidth = sliderVal;
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
    if (mouse.click) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(mouse.lastX, mouse.lastY);
      ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
  }, []);
  return (
      <canvas
        onMouseDown={() => setMouse({ ...mouse, click: true })}
        onMouseMove={(e) => paint(e)}
        onMouseUp={() => setMouse({ ...mouse, click: false })}
        ref={canvasRef}
      />
```

I share a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-kowalevski-b6nyz?file=/src/App.js) with the functional solution